# Can I have multiple views of spreadsheet data which extract and sort from a larger set?

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice

Supposing I have a spreadsheet (Libreoffice ideally but Excel is ok) which has data like this

```
______| Age | Height | Shoe Size | etc...
Adam  | 14  | 180    | 11        | ...
Beth  | 21  | 205    | 14        | ...
Colin | 47  | 192    | 12        | ...
...
...
```

I want to have a master table which I can add to and update, and a number of slave tables. Each slave table would show a subset of the column in the master and sort this view by one of them

For example, the view of ages sorted by shoe size would look like this

```
_____| Age |
Adam | 14  |
Colin| 47  |
Beth | 14  |
```

I want all the views to
a) grow and shrink as rows are added to and from the master,
b) update and re-order as values in the master change.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this an actual problem or are we just "supposing"? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: This is an actual problem. I have data analogous to this. I tried googling but got nowhere, although now CallumDS33 has mentioned pivot tables, so maybe that'll work.

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the Power Query Add-In - this can create filtered and sorted tables based on another table.  It has the advantage over Pivot Tables that the PQ output is a regular Excel table, whereas a Pivot Table output is limited to a summary of numeric values by dynamic rows and/or columns.

PQ also has a lot of data transformation capabilities, that are easy to use, e.g.:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2014/07/10/getting-started-with-power-query-part-i.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should have your source data as a data table and create a series of pivot tables to show subsets of the original data